# How do phonons affect the work function?

Tags: electrons, crystals, electronic-band-theory, phonons

How do phonons affect the work function? Could phonons that are directed towards a single atom, such as in a body-centered cubic crystal, increase the amount of thermal excitation and thus decrease the input of temperature required to eject an electron from that atom?

Answer (score 3):

Careful!  The essence of your question is a good thought but I think you are having several misconceptions.

First of all, it doesn't make sense to talk about a phonon being directed towards a single atom.  Phonons are delocalized.  Secondly, the "input of temperature required to eject an electron" is a dangerous idea.  You need to input **energy** to eject an electron.  Temperature is not energy, though we can often write down an equation which connects **average** energies with the temperature.

However, your basic idea should be correct.  If you heat up a metal then, on average, the electrons should be more thermally excited and the work function should decrease.  For an example in the research literature see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1017556031226#page-1).